# Suspend WKWebView when entering background?

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, wkwebview

Is there a recommended way to suspend or deactivate my `WKWebView` when entering the background? I render complex JavaScript charts in my web view and do not want them to leak memory in the background.

What's the best way to handle this? Then I'd have to reinitialize the entire `WKWebView` or just the JavaScript? Thanks for any help or direction.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, you don't need to do some specific work when entering background, because all heavy-weight work happens in web-process and `WKWebView` is used for rendering only.
However, web-process can be closed by memory pressure; you need to handle it and restore state by implementing method from `WKUIDelegate`:

```
- (void)webViewDidClose:(WKWebView *)webView;
```

I think that the best approach of implementing it is following:

1) If your application is in foreground and webView is shown, restore your `webView` state;

2) Otherwise, wait until application goes to foreground and `webView` becomes visible, and then restore state.